# Xcode iOS Error nw_connection_receive_internal_block_invoke

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, macos

my app starts and then just turns black with the following error:

> 2019-10-19 04:18:27.335330+0200 SAppl[26291:437834] [] > nw_connection_receive_internal_block_invoke [C1] Receive reply failed with error "Operation > canceled"

It may have happened after trying to build the iOS app for Mac, but im not sure If that was the reason.

Would be glad to get any help, since I have no idea what's going on there...

Comment: Please provide some code to show what your app does, and you will be more likely to get an answer.  Without that context, you'd only get speculation on what could be causing this error.

Comment: I wanted speculation, I have no idea which of the files contains the error, but it seems like it is firebase itself

Comment: @Marco Have you found the solution? I am facing the same problem. The app is working fine on iOS 12 devices but when I run it on iOS 13 devices it turned out black.

Comment: Hi, yes, if u switch to iOS 13 it adds a line into the plist file, that you need to remove. the initial error had nothing to do with it

Comment: which line did you remove?